# Why does Vlookup give me the wrong answer?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Can anybody tell me why does vlookup function give me "N4657" as an answer instead of  "N2875" please?

all relevant information is captured in this image. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that you want the vlookup to only return exact matches. I.e. you should change your formula to

```
IDNiv = Worksheetfunction.Vlookup(Me.ComboNiv.Value, Feuil13.Range("B:C"), 2, FALSE)
```

By default, Vlookup is set to return only approximate matches which only works with sorted table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was exactly what was missing!